# Workbox - how to have the service worker file transpiled by webpack?

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am currently generating a service worker file using the GenerateSW plugin from `workbox-webpack-plugin`:

```
new GenerateSW({
    cacheId: 'foo',
    clientsClaim: true,
    inlineWorkboxRuntime: true,
    runtimeCaching: [
         {
              urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com.*/,
              handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
         },
    ],
    skipWaiting: true,
    sourcemap: false,
    swDest: 'sw.js',
}),
```

This resulting `sw.js` file contains code that is produced by the `GenerateSW` plugin injected into it. But, this code is not transpiled and I need it to be, because Google's decision about what ecmascript version to write it in is independent to mine. I can transpile the `sw.js` file using babel after webpack has run, but I was wondering if there is a way for this file to simply be automatically transpiled (preferably using the same `env` information that webpack itself uses)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `workbox-webpack-plugin` v5+, you can [pass in `babelPresetEnvTargets`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW) to configure the transpilation process of the generated service worker.

```
new GenerateSW({
  // Use the Array<string> syntax from
  // https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets
  babelPresetEnvTargets: ['chrome >= 80'],

  // ...other options...
}),
```